# How to correctly select a div inside a table cell

Tags: javascript, delete-row, stoppropagation

I have created a function that inserts table row and data by user's request. I was asked to add a small red square (`div`) in the right corner of table cell, which when clicked, deletes the table row.

I've got so far that I've written a function that removes the table row, but the problem is - it only needs to be done, when the small red `div` is clicked, not when the table cell is clicked. How could this be achieved? I've tried several ways how to address the `div`, but none have worked so far.

Would be really grateful for your assistance.

```
<button class="btn" onclick="createNewTableElement()">Add</button>
<input id="new-item" type="text" value="item">
<table id="main-table" onclick="deleteRow(obj)">
```

```
function createNewTableElement() {
  var inputField = document.getElementById("new-item");
  if (inputField.value == "") {
    return;
  }
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var cellText = document.createTextNode(inputField.value);
  cell.appendChild(div);
  cell.appendChild(cellText);
  row.appendChild(cell);

  obj = document.getElementById("main-table");
  obj.appendChild(row);
}

function deleteRow(e) {
  document.getElementById('main-table').deleteRow(e);
}
```

Comment: On click of div you want to delete row? Or firstly youhave to select multiple rows and then click on delete to rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes in your code. Removed `deleteRow` binded on table and add event only on `div` element, then find parent row element and removed it from table 
Does this help you?

```js
function createNewTableElement() {
  var inputField = document.getElementById("new-item");
  if (inputField.value == "") {
    return;
  }
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.onclick = deleteRow;
  var cellText = document.createTextNode(inputField.value);
  cell.appendChild(div);
  cell.appendChild(cellText);

  row.appendChild(cell);

  obj = document.getElementById("main-table");
  obj.appendChild(row);
}

function deleteRow(e) {
  document.getElementById('main-table').removeChild(e.target.parentElement.parentElement);
}
```

```css
#main-table div {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="createNewTableElement()">Add</button>
<input id="new-item" type="text" value="item">
<table id="main-table">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove onclick from table:

```
  <button class="btn" onclick="createNewTableElement()">Add</button>
  <input id="new-item" type="text" value="item">
  <table id="main-table">
```

Then in same function you are creating row create also red div and event:

```
  function createNewTableElement() {
      var inputField = document.getElementById("new-item");
      if (inputField.value == "") {
        return;
      }
      var row = document.createElement("tr");
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      var div = document.createElement("div");

      div.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
         // the row call parent (table) and tell removes him self
         row.parentNode.removeChild(row); 
      });

      var cellText = document.createTextNode(inputField.value);
      cell.appendChild(div);
      cell.appendChild(cellText);

      row.appendChild(cell);

      obj = document.getElementById("main-table");
      obj.appendChild(row);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

my way..

```js
const mainTable = document.querySelector('#main-table tbody')
  ,   btAdd     = document.getElementById('btn-Add')
  ,   newItem   = document.getElementById('new-item')
  ;
newItem.oninput=()=>
  {
  btAdd.disabled = (newItem.value === '')
  }
btAdd.onclick=()=>
  {
  let newCell = mainTable.insertRow().insertCell()
    ;       
  newCell.textContent = newItem.value
  newCell.appendChild( document.createElement('div'))
  newItem.value = ''
  btAdd.disabled = true
  }
mainTable.onclick=e=>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('td div')) return
  mainTable.deleteRow(  e.target.closest('tr').rowIndex -1 )
  }
```

```css
#main-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 1em;
  }
#main-table thead {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  }
#main-table th {
  padding: .7em;
  width:20em;
  }
#main-table td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: .5em;
  }
#main-table td div {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: crimson;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
#main-table td div:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  }
```

```html
<button id="btn-Add" disabled >Add</button>
<input id="new-item" type="text" placeholder="item">
<table id="main-table">
  <thead> <th>items list</th> </thead>
  <tbody> </tbody>
</table>
```